# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

hello everyone could help me with the following problem, I am using laravel 5.5 and I am doing a system of incidents.

I get this error could help me please to see what is wrong thanks

**error:**

[image]

Comment: [Spanish Stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: ^ ... or write in English if you are able to

Comment: now i think okkz

Comment: @rafael please update your question with text formatted coded

Comment: `$level_id` is null I guess you are getting null in `$projectUser`

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ProjectUser` record that matches your query and that's why `$projectUser` is null and this is causing the error.

Add conditional to check if `$projectUser` exists.